# Transform an Integral bounds from -inf, inf to 0 to 1

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, integral-transforms

Good day,

If i have an integral from -infinity to infinity, how do I change the bounds/limits to 0 to 1? I don't want to give exact question since this is part of an assignment. I know how to figure out the integral but I am suppose to use Monte Carlo estimation.

Thanks

Comment: Need more information.

Comment: lets say your integral is of e^(-x^2) from -inf, to inf. I need it from 0 to 1. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Look up logistic function.

Equivalently,
hyperbolic tan 
(tanh)
goes from
$(-\infty, \infty)
\to (-1, 1)
$.

Then map to 
$(0, 1)$.